# How to compare a Int64 with a Int64

Tags: ios, swift, compare, int64

I working on a Swift program and now I have a problem:

How do you compare a Int64 with a Int64?

```
if(msgCount.value != msg.longLongValue){
```

Error:

```
Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int64' and 'Int64'
```

Comment: Try this if([msgCount.value compare:msg.longLongValue] == NSNotFound) OR if([msgCount.value isEqual:msg.longLongValue]).

Comment: try this if(![msgCount.value isEqual:msg.longLongValue])

Comment: you must tag the question for the language... presumably swift?

Comment: Add your int declaration.

Comment: @Wain I assumed Swift and tagged appropriately, because afaik `Int64` isn't available in ObjC. @Laurens, feel free to correct if I'm wrong.

Comment: It should work. Please add more code to illustrate where those values are coming from.

Comment: Do anyone know how you convert a NSString to a int64?

Comment: Try `Int64(yourNSString as String)`

Comment: Please provide a (small) *self-contained* example demonstrating the problem. You *can* compare two Int64 operands, so there must be something special in your code. Without a reproducible example, it is impossible to give a sensible answer, and the question and its answers would be worthless to future readers.

Comment: Maybe you are comparing Int64 with NSNumber?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly compare for equality

Try this, it will help you:

```
let msgCount : Int64=100
let msg : Int64=101

if(msgCount != msg ){
    // perform your logic here.
}
```